# RegularExpressionValidator - Validate first 2 characters

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am trying to validate a string entered into a textbox.  I want to make sure that the first 2 characters are either 02, 04 or 09.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display = "Dynamic" ControlToValidate = "check_number" ID="rxvValidCheckNumber1" ValidationExpression = "^(02|04|09)" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Valid Check Number required."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

If I enter a string that begins with  02, 04 or 09 the ErrorMessage still fires.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `ValidationExpression = "^(02|04|09).*"`. BTW, is the textbox multiline or singleline?

Comment: Perfect!!!  Thanks so much

Comment: you can even move `0` outside the group `"^0[249].*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ValidationExpression` regex is anchored by default, and thus you need to match the entire input. You may match 0+ chars with `.*`:

```
ValidationExpression = "^(02|04|09).*"
```

To make it a bit more "elegant", you may use `0[249]` after `^`:

```
ValidationExpression = "^0[249].*"
```

The expression matches

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `0` - a `0` digit
- `[249]` - a character class matching either `2` or `4` or`9`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars.

If your textobx is *multiline*, you need to use `(?s)` singleline/dotall modifier

```
ValidationExpression = "(?s)^0[249].*"
```

or (to enable client side validation, the `(?s)` is not supported in JavaScript):

```
ValidationExpression = "^0[249][\s\S]*"
```

where `[\s\S]` matches any char including a line break char.